# Questions about Twitter on Superuser?

Tags: discussion, twitter

Are questions about Twitter (or other web services) on-topic for Superuser?

If not, which StackOverflow-based forum should one use?

Comment: What kinds of questions?

Comment: end-user questions, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927634/tweeting-override

Answer (score 6):

If the questions are related to the programming APIs then the best place would be SO.

If it is about twitter in general, you need to use the twitter support sites, as this is outside of the scope of S[OFU]. Twitter falls under the same category as Facebook discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30475/official-stance-on-facebook-questions-on-su)

Comment: Okay, got it. But then there should be a S[OFU] site for asking these questions. What is the difference between asking a question about Microsoft Word versus a question about Facebook, Twitter, or GMail?

Comment: @Thilo It really depends on what you're asking and what you're doing with those websites and/or what those websites do as well.

Comment: @Thilo - Why? The basics are covered and those sites have their own support systems, we are not here to replace them. If you read the linked discussions it is very well explained.

Answer (score 3):

Not all computer-related questions are covered by S[OFU] sites, and I think this topic falls in the set of things not covered (except, as Diago pointed out, Twitter programming questions).  Questions about video games are another good example.

It's quite arbitrary, but nobody ever claimed that all things computer-related should be covered on one of the sites.